# I don´t see Tier Pricing Panel in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I added a configurable product in Magento2 but I don't see any panel to add special price and tier price. It mus show in Advance Options but I don't see any Advance Pricing Panel

Answer (score 4):

The `Advanced Pricing` tab (and `Tier Price` block) is not available for a configurable product, but available for the simple variants of the configurable product, it is by design.

Comment: In Magento 1.9, it was possible. Anyhow or anyway it can be done in magento2?

Comment: I need this function too. It is to much efford to change it on every simple product of a configurable product.

Comment: Great question @RajatGupta. Magento -- why did you remove that capability?

Answer (score 0):

We can still setup tiers price for configurable products when we create new product, but we cant edit it later.

-Go to Admin-Product-Catalog: add new configurable product

-In base setting-product details tab: fill name, sku, price then SAVE

-Now u can see advanced pricing in advanced setting tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't see "Tier Pricing" in v. 2.2.1. Click "Advanced Pricing" when editing the product and choose "Customer Group Price" to add Fixed and % Discount pricing (aka Tier Pricing).